# Extension's content doesn't load after publishing

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Hi I have been working on a vscode [extension](https://github.com/Mehak-Mehta/VSInterest). After publishing the extension I tried to download it from the marketplace. To my surprise, the extensions content didn't load, it just showed a blank sidebar(though it was working fine in the development). Here is my [package.json](https://github.com/Mehak-Mehta/VSInterest/blob/main/package.json) and [launch.json](https://github.com/Mehak-Mehta/VSInterest/blob/main/launch.json). Can someone tell why this happened?

Comment: Use `vsce package` to generate a .vsix file locally, and then you can open it as a ZIP package to study what's included and how you should tune that.

Comment: Hi @LexLi Thanks for the info! I followed your steps but when I open the file, I can't understand what am I supposed to do? sorry I am new to these thing :/ Any help would be great :)

Comment: You need to add a `.vscodeignore` file https://code.visualstudio.com/api/working-with-extensions/publishing-extension#.vscodeignore and in the meantime revise your `package.config` file to have `dependencies` and `devDependencies`. The former is very important, because those dependencies will be included in .vsix. Study source code of other extensions and you can figure out what I mean.

Comment: @LexLi Thanks for this! But I feel there isn't a problem with package.config or adding .vscodeignore(I already had it added). I feel that there is a problem in activating the sidebar itself because in production the commands are working fine expect the sidebar(I hope I make sense).  Have you made an extension that has a sidebar or know someone that has? I was following https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a5DX5pQ9p5M this but the guy didn't deploy the extension so I got confused :/

Comment: @LexLi I apologize if I am asking too much.

Comment: There must be a sample somewhere for you https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples BTW, your `package.config` only contains `devDependencies`, which doesn't look good, as `vsce` then adds no node module to .vsix.

Comment: Oh thats bad:/ Is there any way I can fix that?

Comment: Also do you know why I am getting https://github.com/Mehak-Mehta/VSInterest/blob/main/2021-05-27%20(2).png these warnings? Because it says can't load content for out/compiled/sidebar.js as sidebar.js has my svelte code converted to js

Comment: Like I said, play with samples to get familiar with the necessary setup. `dependencies` and `devDependencies` are typical Node.js concepts, so you should learn what they are and how to use them via a search engine.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time @LexLi ! You have been a great help! And I agree with you, I should have atleast learned the basics. I don't think that the sidebar would work. Instead I thought of creating it as a panel as that works in production. Anyways, Thanks again!!